# how can i have a working dropdownlist with links from a csv in php

Tags: php, html, csv, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I have a website that loads a CSV, divides it into parts, and shows these parts.

There are 7 parts, and since it is for a music store it is sliced like this:

- the name of the product
- the subname
- the price
- the stock in one shop
- the stock of the other shop
- the group name
- the brandname

What i have now is that it shows 12 products on 1 page, with a next and previous link on top of the page.
The pages are made with the group name, every group has it's own page, so you have a drums page, guitar page, speaker page.
That all works great.
What i programmed in there is a dropdownlist, it drops down a list of brandnames, which should narrow the search for a person who is looking at the products.
Problem is right now, that the dropdown menu works, i see the brands, but they are NONE clickable, only the brands that are currently on the page are shown, so NOT all the brands from that group are shown, only the 12 that are currently showing, when you press next, it shows 12 more brands, but i want them to be shown right on the start.
And the third problem is, when it is showing the brands, it shows them double or triple, depending on how many products have the same brand.
Is there a way what i want, with this code as a basis ?

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=#E2E965 link=black vlink=black alink=black text=#D5DF23>
<style type="text/css">
#nav, #nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
width: 120px;
}
#nav ul {
position: absolute;
width: 120px;
left: -1000px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
left: auto;
}
<!--
a {text-decoration:none}
//-->
body
{
scrollbar-arrow-color: #E2E965;
scrollbar-face-color: #D7182A;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #000000;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #D6DF23;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #00000;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #00000;
scrollbar-track-color: #D6DF23;
}
input:link {text-decoration: none; color: #E2E965;}
input:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #E2E965;}
input:active {text-decoration: none; color: #E2E965;}
.spacer_black {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 5px;
height: 2px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 0px;
font-size: 0px;
background-color: #000000;}
</style>
<table width=800 border=0><td>
</html>
<?PHP
$offset = isset($_GET['offset'])?$_GET['offset']:0;
$LinesToDisplay = 12;
$row = $offset + $LinesToDisplay;
$row2 = $offset - $LinesToDisplay;
$file_handle = fopen("web.txt", "rb");
error_reporting( E_ALL ); // DEBUGGING
$SelectArray=array();
while ((($parts = fgetcsv($file_handle,4096,"|")) !== FALSE)  && ($LinesToDisplay > 0) && (!feof($file_handle)))
{
    //new code
    //skip first $offset lines  

$num = count($parts[6]);
$SelectArray[]=$parts[6];
if ($parts[5] == 9999)
{
if ($offset-- > 0)   
{continue;}
$parts[0] = ucwords(strtolower($parts[0]));
$parts[1] = ucwords(strtolower($parts[1]));
?>
<td>
<?php
echo "<table BACKGROUND='background.jpg' border=0 width=250><td width='243' height='105'>";
echo "<font size=-1 face='helvetica' color=#812990><b>$parts[0]</b></font>";
echo "<i>";
?>
<html>
<div onMouseOver="this.style.color = 'black';" onMouseOut="this.style.color = '#D5DF23';">
</html><?php
echo "<font size=2>-$parts[1]</font>";
echo "</div></i>";
?><html><a href="#" title="Koop nu de <?php echo $parts[0]; ?>" onClick="window.open('form.php?p=<?php echo urlencode($parts[0]); ?>','popuppage','width=400,height=400,top=250,left=250,resizable=0,statusbar=0,titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no');">
<div><img src='ster.jpg' border=0 width='46' align='right'></a>
<a href="#"><img src='envelope.jpg' border=0 width='46' align='right'title="Heeft u een vraag over <?php echo $parts[0]; ?>" onClick="window.open('vraag.php?p=<?php echo urlencode($parts[0]); ?>','popuppage','width=400,height=400,top=250,left=250,resizable=0,statusbar=0,titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no');">
<div></a>
<TABLE BORDER='0' cellpadding='0' CELLSPACING='0'>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH='70' HEIGHT='20' BACKGROUND='pricebackground.jpg' VALIGN='bottom'>
<center>
<font size=2 color=white face='helvetica'>
<b></html>
<?php echo "€  $parts[2]";
?>
</b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php echo "<b><font size=3 color=#D7182A>Op Voorraad In:<br></font>";
      echo ("<font color=black> Amsterdam </font>");
      if ( $parts[3] >= 1 )  echo ("<IMG SRC =green.gif>")."";
      if ( $parts[3] <= 0 )  echo ("<IMG SRC =red.gif>")."";
      echo ("<font color=black> Utrecht </font>");
      if ( $parts[4] >= 1 )  echo ("<IMG SRC =green.gif>")."</td></table></b><p style='margin:9px;'>";
      if ( $parts[4] <= 0 )  echo ("<IMG SRC =red.gif>")."</td></table></b><p style='margin:9px;'>";
      $LinesToDisplay--;
if ($LinesToDisplay/3==intval($LinesToDisplay/3))
{
   echo "<tr><td>";
}
     }}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
<tr align=right>
<select style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-weight: none; font-size: 12; width: 150px; ">
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($SelectArray as $val){
echo "<option value=\"$i\">$val</option>\n";
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
<font color=black><body alink=black vlink=black link=black text=black>
<center><a href="occasiona.php?offset=<?php echo $row2; ?>" align=center>&laquo; previous</a> || <a href="occasiona.php?offset=<?php echo $row; ?>">next &raquo;</a></table></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You determine the offset and then fill `$SelectArray` with 12 lines. That way your script has no way of knowing what else is in the .csv, and it can't display anything except for the data you got from the file.

If you want to display all the brands you need to import the full .csv. Depending on how larget that file is, this might nog be a good idea, because you'll be loading that complete file every time you load the page. If it's a possibility: use a database instead, import the .csv and select only the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the file is only 180kbytes so that is no problem, the problem is how to do it.

Comment: The solution is, like I wrote, add everything from the .csv to your array. Tip: your code is extremely messy, get rid of everything you don't need and focus on reading out the .csv first. This is something you can easily figure out for yourself. If you still don't; post the stripped down code and tell us exactly where it goes wrong after debugging yourself, instead of dumping some code and basically expecting a complete rewrite.